# Why is it "make"?

Tags: poetry, verb-agreement

There's a poem in bahasa indonesia, titled *"Aku Ingin (I want)"* by Sapardi Djoko Damono, translated to english by John H. McGlynn. This is the english version:

> ***I want***
>
> I want to love you simply,
> in words not spoken:
> tinder to the flame which transforms it to ash
>
> I want to love you simply,
> in signs not expressed:
> clouds to the rain which make them evanesce
>
> [source](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7654257-before-dawn)

What I want to ask lies on the last line, especially the word "**make**". **This was originally being questioned in a [blog post (in bahasa indonesia)](http://indonesian-english.com/blog/terjemah-puisi-aku-ingin)**. The OP caught that **make** usage, and his post caught my attention, thus I asked it here to get more understanding of it.

Seems like for Indonesian who reads the poem in bahasa indonesia, the last line interpreted as "*rain that makes the clouds vanish*". Just like the first verse interpreted as "*fire that burns tinder to ashes*". Thus, the word **make** on the last line should have be used by **rain**, that would make it **make*s***. But in the poem's english version, **make** stayed **make**, make it looks like it's used by the **clouds**. Meanwhile on the first verse, both **tinder** and **flame** are singular, thus hard to know to which **transforms** is used.

My question is, why is it **make**, without **s**? Is it a different interpretation, or is there some kind of poetic usage on that word, or is it a common usage for english poem (by english poem, I mean poem using english language)?

Sorry for broken english, and in case I asked in a wrong place, please tell me where should I had asked.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct - the sentence structure calls for "makes". But it's a poem, after all.

Comment: Nice catch.  Well played!

Comment: Hehe I'm not the original asker though, it's just that reading that blog post, it's indeed interesting (well, much part of it because it's a poem I really love), and make me very curious as well. Question edited to give the original asker more credit.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem as simple as the comments above suggest. The translator used transforms instead of transform. That means using make instead of makes was also intentional.

I want to love you simply,
 in signs not expressed:
 **clouds to the rain** which make them evanesce

You have to take "clouds to the rain" as an antecedent for the relative pronoun, which. In other words and more details;

**tinder to the flame** **(antecedent here)** which **transforms** it (it means tinder) to ash

**clouds to the rain** **(antecedent here)** which **make** them (them means clouds) evanesce

**Tinder is something that causes flame and gets burned by "flame" to ashes.** Literally, it causes its own death.

**Clouds are things that cause rain and get washed out by "rain" to disappear.** Literally, they also cause thier own death.

It is "very" logical and grammatical to use "make" instead of "makes"

Does it make sense to you? Hope it helps.